# Payment methods in custom checkout page

Tags: payment-methods, onestepcheckout

I am working on building a custom checkout page for my new module. Can anyone say how can I include payment methods into my custom checkout page. I need to integrate Paypal and Authorizenet methods currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.X:

To display currently active payment methods on custom checkout module is to override block Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment_Methods with custom one.

In that corresponding phtml file just call $methods = $this->getMethods(); which will give all active payment methods.

Refer following two file:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml
app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Payment\Methods.php
```

Magento 2:
 write following in your block file.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentHelper,
) {       
    $this->_paymentHelper = $paymentHelper;   
}

/**
 * Get all payment methods
 * 
 * @return array
 */ 
public function getAllPaymentMethods() 
{
    return $this->_paymentHelper->getPaymentMethods();
}
```

Now you can getAllPaymentMethods() method from your phtml file.

Comment: How Do I do this with magento 2

Comment: I have updated my answer with Magento 2 code.